# Unwind segue to last view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

From the examples I've seen unwind segue needs a view controller to unwind to.  If i just want to go back one controller in my storyboard is there a simple command for this?

Comment: How did you go "forward" to that view controller?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561735/what-are-unwind-segues-for-and-how-do-you-use-them

Comment: @michael - this example requires specific destination segues

Comment: @jturnton I used preformseguewithidentifier to go forward or I just used a segue created in IB.  I don't keep track of previous view controller however

Comment: which type of segue are you using? push, custom or any other?

Comment: Maybe I'm looking at this wrong -> I just want to programmatically hit the back button basically.

Comment: You're not looking at it wrong, you just didn't explain it very well :) Answered now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you've pushed onto a navigation controller (push segues, with a visible back button) then you use this code to go back:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

If you've used modal segues, use this:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

In both cases `self` is the currently visible view controller.

Comment: Just in case anyone needs it, `dismissViewControllerAnimated` doesn't (at least, for me) work for **custom segues**. Use `self.performSegueWithIdentifier("idCustomSegueUnwind", sender: self)`. Does anyone know how my custom segue will be performed when `dismissViewControllerAnimated` is called?

Answer (score 0):

In the newest version of swift it will work like this:

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Assuming you call this in the view controller script.